# Question about proof of weak derivative of Heaviside function

Tags: solution-verification, calculus-of-variations, weak-derivatives

I am reading the book "Introduction to Calculus of Variations" by Bernard Dacorogna, and on chapter 1.4 of Sobolev Spaces, in example 1.29 it is shown that the Heaviside function

\begin{equation*}
H(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
1 & \text { if } x>0 \\
0 & \text { if } x \leq 0
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation*}

has no weak derivative in, say, $\Omega=]-1,1[$. I understand the proof, but I'm confused at the end of the following step:

> Assume, for the sake of contradiction, that $H'=\delta \in L^1_{loc}(\Omega)$ and let us prove that we reach a contradiction. Let $\varphi \in C^{\infty}_0(]0,1[)$ be arbitrary and extend it to $]-1,0[$ by $\varphi\equiv 0$. We therefore have by definition that
> \begin{equation*}
> \begin{aligned}
> \int_{-1}^1 \delta(x) \varphi(x) d x & =-\int_{-1}^1 H(x) \varphi^{\prime}(x) d x=-\int_0^1 \varphi^{\prime}(x) d x \\
> & =\varphi(0)-\varphi(1)=0.
> \end{aligned}
> \end{equation*}

What confuses me is the last equality: why must $\varphi(0)=\varphi(1)$ if $\varphi \in C^{\infty}_0(]0,1[)$? For example, $\varphi(x)=x, x \in]0,1[$ would be in $C^{\infty}_0(]0,1[)$, but $\varphi(0)\neq \varphi(1)$.

Comment: No it is not, it is smooth but does not vanish at the boundary which is the meaning of the subscript $0$.

Comment: @Ian According to the book, $C_0(\Omega)=\{u \in C(\Omega): \operatorname{supp} u \subset \Omega$ is compact $\}$. In fact, the contradiction comes from the conclusion that "This would imply that $\varphi(0)=0$ for every $\varphi \in C^{\infty}_0(]-1,1[)$, which is clearly absurd." (After some extra steps in the proof).

Comment: The support of $x$ would be the whole of $(0,1)$ which is not compact. Do you know $e^{-1/(1-x^2)}1_{|x|<1}$ the standard example of compactly supported smooth function?

Comment: @ImHackingXD There is a nuanced topological issue going on here; you might say "the support of $u$ is $[0,1]$ which is compact". But that is not correct, because the word "compact" here means "compact as a subset of $\Omega$ (which in that context is $(0,1)$)". This means that the support of $\varphi$ in this description is a closed subset of $[a,b]$ for some $0<a<b<1$.

Comment: Thank you to both of you, now I understand the nuance that I was missing. With that in mind, since the support must be of the form $[a,b]$, for $0<a<b<1$, then taking the limit to $x=0$ or $x=1$, its value must be $0$.